# Can I have fixed width columns with different number of columns per row?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have a grid with the following specifications:

- In screens < 400 pixels, show 1 column per row
- In screens > 400 pixels and < 800 pixels, show 2 columns per row
- In screens > 800 pixels, show 4 columns per row
- In all screen sizes, each column should have a width of 25% of screen size

I wrote the following code, which works, my question is can we accomplish the same result using display:flex?

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.col {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}

@media all and (min-width: 360px) {
  .col {
    clear: none;
  }
  .col:nth-child(2n + 1) {
    clear: left;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 720px) {
  .col {
    clear: none !important;
  }
}

.clearfix {
  overflow: auto;
  zoom: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="col">Column 1</div>
  <div class="col">Column 2</div>
  <div class="col">Column 3</div>
  <div class="col">Column 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your code. In the meantime look up css media queries.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because at this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: i researched and i wrote code, before voting down read carefully, you obviously didn't understand the question. @Rob

Comment: @G-Cyr He's wanting a more elegant solution than what he wrote.

Comment: flexgrid ? do you mean display:flex, or display:grid ? ;)

Comment: display: flex @G-Cyr

Comment: @therayess Now you are asking for opinion and someone to write markup for you. You need to ask a specific question that can give you a specific answer.

Comment: It is a specific question, can the same be done using display:flex, if yes, how, if no, that's the answer. @Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the flex model, you need to reset the flex-basis value and allow wrapping.

At small width , flex is not needed;

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

@media all and (min-width: 360px) {
  .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .col {
    flex: 1 0 25%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .col:nth-child(even) {
    margin-right: 50%;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 1px;/*see me */
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 720px) {
  .col:nth-child(even) {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="col">Column 1</div>
  <div class="col">Column 2</div>
  <div class="col">Column 3</div>
  <div class="col">Column 4</div>
</div>
```

A tutorial/reminder that can be usefull : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

---

edit and example for infos via bootstrap-4 https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/mMobBa

```css
[class] {
  border: 1px solid black;   
}
.col-sm-3:nth-child(even) {
  margin-right:50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row d-flex flex-wrap">
  <div class=" col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-12">Column 1</div>
  <div class=" col-sm-3 mr-md-0 col-md-3 col-12">Column 2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-12">Column 3</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3  mr-md-0 col-md-3 col-12">Column 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that won't retain the width of 25% for the 2 columns view, they will become 50% in width. the requirement is that at all screen sizes the column widths should always be 25%.

Comment: @therayess ,  i updated the snippet. That you left empty half of the box is what  i do not understand here :)  .... or do you seek for each 2n+1 to fill up space left ?

Comment: It was intended to leave up the spacing to retain 25% of width in any case.

Comment: Thanks for your provided solution! it was exactly what i was looking for, i can use the margin left and right and make them work as columns too..perfect. thanks :) @G-Cyr